# Find the average of numbers using MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

I have been trying to write some code to find the average of numbers using MapReduce.

I am trying to use global counters to reach my goal but I am not able to set the counter value in the `map` method of my Mapper and I am also not able to retrive the counter value in the `reduce` method of my Reducer.

Do I have to use a global counter in `map` anyway (e.g. by using `incrCounter(key, amount)` of the provided `Reporter`)? Or would you suggest any different logic to get the average of some numbers?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: No.this is not homework...this is the project i m working on..

Comment: Hey,I don't have the code ryt now..i can post it on monday.. but if u have worked on it can u plz help??

Comment: We *cannot* help you without code.  That's not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: @the_silent_lord StackOverflow is about **helping you fix** your code, not **giving away** full implementations.

Comment: okk..I will surely post the code..

Comment: Another suggestion you might want to look into is using Pig, which abstracts you away from the Map Reduce details and into a higher level language. They have an example on the overview page which may be similar to what you're trying to do - http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigOverview

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The logic is quite simple:
If all the number have the **same key**, then the mapper sent all the values you want to find the average of with that same key. Because of this, in the reducer you can sum the values in the iterator. You can then keep a **counter** on number time the iterator works, which solves the issue of how many items are to be averaged. Finally, after the iterator, you can find the average by dividing the sum by the number of items.

Be careful, **this logic will not work** if the combiner class is set as the same class as reducer...

Comment: I think this approach makes useless the concept of MapReduce, because since the numbers have the same key, then there will be only one reducer .. 
A better approach could be to split the input in buckets (assigning keys), and the number of buckets should be sqrt(n), where n is the number of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Use all 3 Mapper/Combiner/Reducer to solve the issue.
Refer to below link for complete code & explanation

http://alchemistviews.blogspot.com/2013/08/calculate-average-in-map-reduce-using.html

Answer (score 2):

Average is sum / size. If sum is something like sum = k1 + k2 + k3 + ... , you might divide by size after or during summing up. So the average is also k1 / size + k2 / size + k3 / size + ...

The Java 8 code is simple:

```
    public double average(List<Valuable> list) {
      final int size = list.size();
      return list
            .stream()
            .mapToDouble(element->element.someValue())
            .reduce(0,(sum,x)->sum+x/size);
    }
```

So you first map each value of your elements in the list to double and then summing up via the reduce function.

Comment: Using an extra step for the size, you are actually not calculating the average with map-reduce here but only the sum. The tricky part is doing it all at once...

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic mean is an aggregate function which is not distributive but algebraic. According to [Han et al.](https://safaribooks.freepaper.me/library/view/data-mining-concepts/9780123814791/xhtml/ST0050_CHP004.html#P0495_CHP004) an aggregate function is distributive if:

> [...] it can be computed [...] as follows. Suppose [..] data are partitioned into *n* sets. We apply the function to each partition, resulting in *n* aggregate values. If the result derived by applying the function to the *n* aggregate values is the same as that derived by applying the function to the entire data set (without partitioning), the function can be computed in a distributed manner.

Or in other words, it has to be associative and commutative. An aggregate function however is algebraic according to [Han et al.](https://safaribooks.freepaper.me/library/view/data-mining-concepts/9780123814791/xhtml/ST0050_CHP004.html#P0505_CHP004) if:

> [...] it can be computed by an algebraic function with m arguments (where m is a bounded positive integer), each of which is obtained by applying a distributive aggregate function.

For the arithmetic mean this is just *avg = sum/count*. Obviously you need to carry a count additionally. But using a global counter therefor seems to be a misuse. The [API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Counter.html) describes `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter` as follows:

> A named counter that tracks the progress of a map/reduce job.

Counters should be typically used for statistics about jobs anyway but not as part of calculations during the data processing itself.

So everything you have to do within a partition is to add your numbers up and track their count together with the sum *(sum, count)*; a simple approach could be a string like `<sum><separator><count>`.

In the mapper the count will be always 1 and the sum is the raw value itself. To reduce the map files already you could use the combiner and process the aggregates like *(sum_1 + ... + sum_n, count_1 + ... + count_n)*. This must be repeated in the reducer and finished by the final calculation *sum/count*. **Keep in mind that this approach is independent from the used key!**

Finally here is a simple example using the raw [crime statistics of the LAPD](https://data.lacity.org/d/y8tr-7khq) which should calculates the "average crime time" in Los Angeles:

```
public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {
    enum Counters {
        DISCARDED_ENTRY
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ToolRunner.run(new Driver(), args);
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = getConf();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(configuration);
        job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setCombinerClass(Combiner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : -1;
    }
}

public class Mapper extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<
    LongWritable,
    Text,
    LongWritable,
    Text
> {

    @Override
    protected void map(
        LongWritable key,
        Text value,
        org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<
            LongWritable,
            Text,
            LongWritable,
            Text
        >.Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // parse the CSV line
            ArrayList<String> values = this.parse(value.toString());

            // validate the parsed values
            if (this.isValid(values)) {

                // fetch the third and the fourth column
                String time = values.get(3);
                String year = values.get(2)
                    .substring(values.get(2).length() - 4);

                // convert time to minutes (e.g. 1542 -> 942)
                int minutes = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0, 2))
                    * 60 + Integer.parseInt(time.substring(2,4));

                // create the aggregate atom (a/n)
                // with a = time in minutes and n = 1
                context.write(
                    new LongWritable(Integer.parseInt(year)),
                    new Text(Integer.toString(minutes) + ":1")
                );
            } else {
                // invalid line format, so we increment a counter
                context.getCounter(Driver.Counters.DISCARDED_ENTRY)
                    .increment(1);
            }
    }

    protected boolean isValid(ArrayList<String> values) {
        return values.size() > 3 
            && values.get(2).length() == 10 
            && values.get(3).length() == 4;
    }

    protected ArrayList<String> parse(String line) {
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        String current = "";
        boolean escaping = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
            char c = line.charAt(i);

            if (c == '"') {
                escaping = !escaping;
            } else if (c == ',' && !escaping) {
                values.add(current);
                current = "";
            } else {
                current += c;
            }
        }

        values.add(current);

        return values;
    }
}

public class Combiner extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<
    LongWritable,
    Text,
    LongWritable,
    Text
> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(
        LongWritable key,
        Iterable<Text> values,
        Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Long n = 0l;
        Long a = 0l;
        Iterator<Text> iterator = values.iterator();

        // calculate intermediate aggregates
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String[] atom = iterator.next().toString().split(":");
            a += Long.parseLong(atom[0]);
            n += Long.parseLong(atom[1]);
        }

        context.write(key, new Text(Long.toString(a) + ":" + Long.toString(n)));
    }
}

public class Reducer extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<
    LongWritable,
    Text,
    LongWritable,
    Text
> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(
        LongWritable key, 
        Iterable<Text> values, 
        Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Long n = 0l;
        Long a = 0l;
        Iterator<Text> iterator = values.iterator();

        // calculate the finale aggregate
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String[] atom = iterator.next().toString().split(":");
            a += Long.parseLong(atom[0]);
            n += Long.parseLong(atom[1]);
        }

        // cut of seconds
        int average = Math.round(a / n);

        // convert the average minutes back to time
        context.write(
            key,
            new Text(
                Integer.toString(average / 60) 
                    + ":" + Integer.toString(average % 60)
            )
        );
    }
}
```